# Android Load a FBX or Collada(.dae) into Android Studio Activity

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d, collada, fbx

I need load a 3d model with animation in a project, but I don't find how load those models, only .obj, but they obj models not have animation. 
The app isn't a game, is a normal app but in one section have the animated avatar, and I need change textures like the hair color, color of skin, etc.

Comment: Question is valid and I think question is like how to load .dae files in android studio(android java)

Answer (score 1):

Android SDK including NDK doesn't even load OBJ files.

1. You have to make your own loader for the file format you want to use using Java or CPP

or

2. You can use a third party library like Open Asset Import Library (http://assimp.sourceforge.net/)

You can change dynamic variables like color of skin or hair by passing vertices as color vertices corresponding to the position vertices, and then you can process the data in the shader code.